# Python unit test comparing list values

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertions

So I am currently trying to write a simple test that will just compare the value of one list to another in a separate py file. I'm familiar with the `assertListEquals(a,b)`but I may be using it incorrectly or im missing something. When I run the module I get absolutely no response from the testsuite. No Error codes or anything. Maybe you guys can help me.

Here is my testsuite

```
from MyList import main
import unittest

class TestSuite(unittest.TestCase):



    def test_ValueContains(self):

        print('test')

        testList = [1,2,3]
        value = MyList
        self.assertListEqual(testList,value)


if __name__== "main":
            unittest.main()
```

And here is the MyList.py

```
def main():

    MyList = [1,2,3]

main()
```

All I want to do is be able to check if `MyList == testList` and get a 'Ok' when running the test.

Sorry I'm new to unit tests

Comment: I get `NameError: global name 'myList' is not defined` error and it is  what is really is - `MyList` is defined inside the `main()` function scope, it is not imported.

Comment: Try adding print statements in the test to see if its running at all. Check the documentation for command line arguments. And in your separate module it doesn't look lile you are setting a global variable.

Comment: Hey @daveydave400. I added a print statement within in the test and as you expected it seems that the test isn't running at all.. I added my updated code for the test suite. I'm not sure why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your code as such:

```
def main():
    MyList = [1,2,3]
    return MyList
```

and

```
from MyList import main
import unittest

class TestSuite(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_ValueContains(self):

        print('test')

        testList = [1,2,3]
        value = main()
        self.assertListEqual(testList,value)

if __name__== "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The problem was that you were running your main method without ever storing the value. This can be achieved by returning the value instead of simply assigning it.

You also needed to change the if statement at the bottom from

```
if __name__ == "main":
```

to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

as that is the correct naming convention.

Comment: How to unit test two lists with floating values?